# Is there a library similar to lxml or nokogiri for Java?

Tags: java, screen-scraping

I want to do some screen scraping, ideally using CSS selectors and not XPath. Is there a library similar to ones in Ruby or Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are dozen of screen scraping library written in Java. Just to cite a few :

> - [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) - a SAX-compliant parser written in Java that, instead
>     of parsing well-formed or valid XML,
>     parses HTML as it is found in the
>     wild: nasty and brutish, though quite
>     often far from short. TagSoup is
>     designed for people who have to
>     process this stuff using some
>     semblance of a rational application
>     design. By providing a SAX interface,
>     it allows standard XML tools to be
>     applied to even the worst HTML.
> - [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jerichohtml.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) - Jericho HTML Parser is a simple but powerful
>     java library allowing analysis and
>     manipulation of parts of an HTML
>     document, including some common
>     server-side tags, while reproducing
>     verbatim any unrecognised or invalid
>     HTML. It also provides high-level HTML
>     form manipulation functions. t is
>     neither an event nor tree based
>     parser, but rather uses a combination
>     of simple text search, efficient tag
>     recognition and a tag position cache.
>     The text of the whole source document
>     is first loaded into memory, and then
>     only the relevant segments searched
>     for the relevant characters of each
>     search operation.
> - [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) - HtmlCleaner reorders individual elements and
>     produces well-formed XML from dirty
>     HTML. It follows similar rules that
>     the most of web-browsers use in order
>     to create document object model. A
>     user may provide custom tag and rule
>     set for tag filtering and balancing.
> - [NekoHTML](http://www.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/html/) - NekoHTML is a simple HTML scanner and tag balancer that
>     enables application programmers to
>     parse HTML documents and access the
>     information using standard XML
>     interfaces. The parser can scan HTML
>     files and "fix up" many common
>     mistakes that human (and computer)
>     authors make in writing HTML
>     documents. NekoHTML adds missing
>     parent elements; automatically closes
>     elements with optional end tags; and
>     can handle mismatched inline element
>     tags.

And many more at [HTML Screen Scraping Tools written in Java](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/screen-scraping-tools-written-in-java). But these are IMO the best to deal with any kind of content (understand all kind of crap) as I mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009897/recommend-an-alternative-to-jtidy/2010028#2010028). This might not be an issue for you though.

Just in case, maybe check out the thread [Nokogiri pure Java status](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk/browse_thread/thread/275c2f6cb610f71f?pli=1).

**Update:** A new project has been released (the 2010-01-31), [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which offers a [*selector-syntax to find elements*](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). See its website for more details and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best/2170950#2170950) from its author.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot) through jRuby. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193269/server-side-css-selectors) for more details about it.