# Tear subString from within HTML tags with JAVA

Tags: java, html, string, tags

let say i have a string like this "`neverMind<b>What is up</b>neverMind`" and I want to take out the What is up using regexp with JAVA. Someone told me that using matcher will be the best. Can anyone show me how to do it using Matcher?
Other solutions are welcome too!
Thanks!

Comment: sorry, the "What is up" is surrounded with the bold tags which is not shown in the question ("<b>","</b>")

Comment: Select that block of text and click the `101 010` button.

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? Are you asking for ready solution or have tried and haven't succeeded? And why you didn't ask the "someone" who told you that using matcher is the best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your string is simple like this all the time, you could use the java [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) indeed. But if your strings get more complicated and you want to extract contents from nested structures, you should really use a HTML parser.

For choosing the right parser look at this question: [Which HTML parser is best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best).

If you stay with patterns, your regex will look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "<b>(.*?)</b>" );
Matcher m = pattern.matcher( "neverMind<b>What is up</b>neverMind" );
if( m.find() ) {
    String theStringYouAreLookingFor = m.group( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it without matcher

```
        String a="neverMind<b>What is up</b>neverMind";
    int index1=a.indexOf(">");
    int index2=a.indexOf("</b>");
    String finalString=a.substring(index1+1, index2);
    System.out.println(finalString);
```