# Extraction of HTML Tags using Java

Tags: java, html

I wanted to extract the various HTML tags available from the source code of a web page is there any method in Java to do that or do HTML parser support this?

I want to seperate all the HTML tags .

Comment: Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best

Answer (score 1):

Java comes with an XML parser with similar methods to the DOM in JavaScript:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(html);
doc.getElementById("someId");
doc.getElementsByTagName("div");
doc.getChildNodes();
```

The document builder can take many different inputs (input stream, raw html string, etc).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

The cyber neko parser is also good if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CyberNeko HTML Parser](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. 
If your html is valid XML -- you can use XML parser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If his HTML is valid XML, then it's actually XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `util` method to extract tags.

Check for `<` and `/>` or `>` for complete tag and write those tags to another file.

Comment: Come on! A typo every now and then is not that bad, but 4 wrong words in the first 6?

Comment: Before your edit you had "u can write ur won uitill". You (correctly) replaced "u" with "you" ('though it should be capitalized), "ur" with "your" and "uitill" with "util". "won" should still be "own". And regarding your content: I wouldn't suggest trying to implement a HTML parser from scratch. It's a tough problem and others have already (mostly) solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) in one project, was pretty happy with it.

Edit: If you check the samples page, the **parser** sample does pretty much what you're asking for.