# How to replace till the first occurrence of the HTML <b>...</b> tag

Tags: java, html, string

```
String tmp = "4 days ago <b>...</b> Jon founded the video <b>Yahoo</b>! and also";

I want to remove "4 days ago <b>...</b>" from the string.
```

Please let me know what is the best way to strip till the first tag.

Comment: You should use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best).

Comment: A regular expression, look at the api docs if you have questions post what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to use "real" HTML parser. But you can do it with regular expression as well. Try something like this:

`String result = tmp.replaceFirst(".*?<b>.*?</b>", "");`

Comment: This is a non-lazy one which might be more efficient: String result = tmp.replaceFirst("[^>]*>[^>]*>", "");