# Separate elements and tags of an html in java using scanner

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, java.util.scanner

I am new to programming and just started learning java. I would like to try and open an HTML file and divide it tag-per-tag and content per content.

I just learned how to scan using Scanner and then check for hasNext() but I figured out it only checks for spaces.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader("simple.html"));
while (input.hasNext())
{   
String content = input.next().toString();
System.out.println(content);
}
```

The problem is...

```
//INPUT
<html><head><title>Hello</title></head>
<body>
<table border=1>
Hello World!
</table>
</body>
</html>

//DESIRED OUTPUT
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello
</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
Hello
World!
</table>
</body>
</html>

//WHAT MY CODE OUTPUTS
<html><head><title>Hello</title></head>
<body>
<table
border=1>
Hello
World!
</table>
</body>
</html
```

Can anyone help me? I'm stuck.
A step by step guide will be appreciated.

I've seen some third-party programs that automates such but I would like to learn it the "coding way". Coz I'm trying to self-study programming, specifically Java...

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: A `Scanner` is not really the tool for parsing HTML, for that you need an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-parsing/info) like [tag:jsoup] or similar.

Comment: hi.

first, thank you for replying...
but as I stated, I don't like to use 3rd party softwares.

if scanner isn't the right way, can you suggest another way then?

Comment: The right way is to use a 3rd party tool for parsing XML.

Comment: uhm, isn't there a way to separate tags without using 3rd party?
I know that's maybe kinda too much but I would love to learn how... Thanks!

Comment: To employ a parser is not strictly '3rd party' in the way I think you mean. After all you didn't write the scanner object either.

It's right to be concerned about using 3rd party written code in your projects. Often they do things you don't need, may not be fast, or indeed could be trouble. 

Look into StringTokenizor, or if you need to get the 'job done' without writing your own parser: 

I found this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best

Comment: Parsing HTML is a really hard task, and doing it yourself is a really bad idea, especially if you're a newbie. I understand you would like to avoid using a third-party library if you just use one or two  trivial utility methods. But avoiding an HTML parser when you need to parse HTML is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The scanner isn't the tool in your case, because "" are separate tokens.

You need to scan input character by character, with flag if you are inside tag or not. Something like that (pseudocode)

```
if char is > flag off
if char is < flag on
if char is whitespace and not flag than print ENDLINE
else if char is (ENDLINE or whitespace) and flag print whitespace
else print char
```

Now you can learn by making Java from pseudocode.