# How to find the number of embedded objects in a response

Tags: java, object, response

In web applications we send a http request to web server and we get the response back. Our browser will render that response in browser and displays it. I want to calculate the number of embedded objects such as images,video,audio files,CSS etc in the response page.

I got the JavaScript code

`document.write(document.images.length)`

and using jQuery code

`alert($("img").size());`

But I want to calculate the number of embedded objects in a response HTML page using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use any HTML Parser in java. There are many parsers available. Using the parser you can find the number of  and other objects.

**Sample Links :**

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084148/html-parser-in-java

[Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)

Comment: Is there no way other than html parser  for counting number of embedded objects in a web page(http response)??

Comment: @user2049541 i know this option only.

Comment: thank you.it is helpful.but i have doubt whether it give all the embedded objects present in a page.since page not only contains images,css,links but also some other media like video,any graphics files etc..so can i get those using this

Comment: I think using "<embed />"  tag we can get.

Comment: You think this is a answer for your question then please make it as answer.