# Get nodes in html document contains word

Tags: java, c++, python, c, parsing

I want to write a script that checks a
document for keywords and specifies html document nodes in which they are contained (possibly
assign a unique identifier).

I am not a professional programmer and do not know the strength of low-level languages ​​and things as PLO.. I'm afraid of doing something very bad and unsupported.

How is it possible to isolate the desired nodes?

My experience - js and php - php only for very simple things. Also, I
do not want to use the opportunity to work
with js nodes. My thoughts:

- to make a string of html
- verify the existence of the words on the page
- if the word on page exists: foreach node in body element I get first and last positions
  (for example, we see opening tag  for each character we initially know
  position and therefore we calculate the first
  position where the tag is opened and last where closed. And so on for all nodes).

We know the position of the word (eg 192,
199) and check in what range it got (in this
case, these bands - nodes html document).

I need ideas from experienced programmers.
It does not matter what language you are
programming (except for web-oriented)-
every opinion is important to me. It is likely
that there are libraries that solve such
problems. I very much hope that you will
understand me. English is not my native
language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this kind of thing. It is a Python library that allows you to parse XML/HTML documents really quickly. You could quite quickly get something running that extracts the text from each div element I would have thought. Then using Pythons built-in string manipulation tools I'm sure searching for particular words would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a html parser. Refer

[Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)

After that, you need to use xpath feature to extract whichever node.