# Match new line using regular expressions java?

Tags: java, regex

I like to get html content using regular expressions. I have problems when the content is written in multiple lines. No matches are found. Here is the regular expression that I use:

```
String regExpContent = "<div class=\"views-field views-field-body\">(\\s+)<span class=\"field-content\">([\\:\\,\\w\\s\\.\\„\\”\\-\\(\\)0123456789(&nbsp;)(\r?\n)]+)</span>(\\s+)</div>";
Pattern regExpMatcherContent = Pattern.compile(regExpContent,
            Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

I use `(\r?\n)` to match new line. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please use an [HTML parser](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String html = "<div class=\"views-field views-field-body\">...</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element body = doc.body();

Elements fieldContent = body.select("div.views-field-body span.field-content");
```

The use of regex for parsing HMTL has been discouraged so often that I won't repeat any of the arguments here. Suffice it to say that you really should not do it.

Comment: Then you should use jSoup nevertheless and explain to your teacher that real developers don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using regex to parse html.You should use an [html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best).

---

To answer your question

Your `Pattern.DOTALL` is redundant because you are not using `.` anywhere in your regex

`\s` in your regex would match newlines because it is similar to `[\r\n\t ]`

The problem is with your `[\\:\\,\\w\\s\\.\\„\\”\\-\\(\\)0123456789(&nbsp;)(\r?\n)]+`..It should `([:,\\w\\s.„”()-]|&nbsp;)+`