# Replacing link tag using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using java. And i want to find then replace hyperlink and anchor text of tag `<a>` html. I knew i must use: `replace()` method but i'm pretty bad about regex.
An example:

```
<a href="http://example.com">anchor text 1</a>
```

will be replaced by:

```
<a href="http://anotherweb.com">anchor text 2</a>
```

Could you show my the regex for that purpose? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't use regex, use `HTML` [parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best).

Comment: Is it a specific link and text that you want to replace or is it that you want to replace all links and all text to `http://anotherweb.com` and `anchor text 2`?

Comment: I want to replace all links and all text in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use a `replaceAll` with the regex:

```
<a href=\"[^\"]+\">[^<]+</a>
```

And replace with:

```
<a href=\"http://anotherweb.com\">anchor text 2</a>
```

`[^\"]+` and `[^<]+` are negated class and will match all characters except `"` and `<` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex for this task. You should use some HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
String str = "<a href='http://example.com'>anchor text 1</a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
str = doc.select("a[href]").attr("href", "http://anotherweb.com").first().toString();

System.out.println(str);
```