# Remove data between two strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to remove data between two string as below

```
<PACKET>752</PACKET> 
  <TIME>23-Oct-2013 12:05:46 GMT Standard Time</TIME> 
  <INTERVAL>2</INTERVAL> 

<HEADER>hi this should not be printed only</HEADER>
<DATA></DATA>
```

In this I have to remove data between **<HEADER>** and **</HEADER>** . 
Can any body give me regex for this?

Comment: Using Regex for such problems is not recommended, instead use [HTML Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can do the job with RegEx:

```
String str="b1<HEADER>aaaaa</HEADER>b2";
String newstring = str.replaceAll("<HEADER[^>]*>([^<]*)<\\/HEADER>", "");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

This prints `b1b2`

In the case that you have other tags inside `<HEADER>` the above will fail. Consider the below example :

```
String str = "b1<HEADER>aa<xxx>xx</xxx>aaa</HEADER>b2";
String newstring = str.replaceAll("<HEADER[^>]*>([^<]*)<\\/HEADER>", "");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

This prints: `b1<HEADER>aa<xxx>xx</xxx>aaa</HEADER>b2`

To overcome this and remove also the containing tags use this:

```
newstring = str.replaceAll("<HEADER.+?>([^<]*)</HEADER>", "");
```

This will print `b1b2`.

Answer (score 1):

Maroun's right that it's not a good idea, but if you have to do it then this might work:

```
(?ms)(.*<HEADER>).*(<\/HEADER>.*)
```

This captures everything up to and including `<HEADER>` in group 1, and everything from `</HEADER>` onwards in group 2. You can then concatenate the two to remove the bit in the middle.

See here: http://regex101.com/r/bC2eQ7

Comment: I use System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?ms)(.*<HEADER>).*(<\\/HEADER>.*)", "")); but not work.

Comment: @dilip_jindal: That's because you're replacing the whole string with an empty string if you do that. As mentioned, you need to use the capture groups, which you can't do with `String.replaceAll`. You need to use a matcher: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx replaces everything inside the  tag with en empty String:

```
String input = "<PACKET>752</PACKET>...<HEADER>hi this should be printed only</HEADER><DATA></DATA>";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=<HEADER>).*?(?=</HEADER>)", "");
```

Result:

```
<PACKET>752</PACKET>...<HEADER></HEADER><DATA></DATA>
```