# How to read specific information from a website

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to create a java program which can read and output the positions of football teams in a league table from the BBC website.

I've found and used this code so far, which shows all of the HTML.

```
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/table");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

But I then want to search through the HTML to find out which team is in which position. For example, this is the bit I'm interested in from the HTML code

[image: http://gyazo.com/033b51d8513f69a47a49bff18e95218c.png]

but I'm not sure how I'd search for that. I've been looking at Regular Expressions but I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Parsing HTML as a String is quite tedious, take a look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) instead for a much easier API, if you really need the info from a webpage.

Comment: take a look at: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-extract-html-tag-string-regex-pattern-matcher-group

Comment: One tip is to see how the information is getting onto the page.  If the page is dynamically being loaded and the information is being presented though a JavaScript function, you could just parse the file the JavaScript is loading.  It is much simpler to parse a JSON file than it is to parse a verbose and wordy HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Java libraries that parse HTML? Take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), as top-voted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best) SO question. Both are actively updated and will most likely fit your needs.

It'll also make it much easier for you to update your code if they decide to change their markup in the future, compared to hand-crafting regular expressions.