# reading html file line by line using java

Tags: java, html

I want to read a html file line and line and need to store the elements .for textbox i have to  store the id,name,type attribute values into some collection. In the same i need to get attributes for checkbox, radiobox etc

Is their any API to parse the html file line by line.

Comment: Before attempting to parse HTML with anything, take a look at the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **DOM Parser** and read all Elements and Attributes. Or you could use this library([jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)) which is based on the DOM Parser.

Comment: I would have recommended jsoup, simple and easy to use with very good documentation. +1

Comment: reading the input elements using jsoup like "doc.getElementsByTag("input")". By using this i am able to read the attribute values. but the problem is, i should not hardcode the word "input" or "form" or "textarea".

Answer (score 1):

Use Class [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
 StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mypage.html"));
      String str;
      while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
          contentBuilder.append(str);
      }
      in.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("HTML File Read Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }
 String content = contentBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, since that doesn't make sense: HTML has no useful notion of "line". What you need to do is read the HTML **element by element**.

There are lots of parsers for XML but HTML is a more lenient, so you need a special parser for it. Try [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/%24).

Answer (score 0):

[NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) is one of the many html parsers that you could use.