# Replace start and end text with empty

Tags: java, regex

I have html like bellow

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv ...............
    ...................
</head> ..............
...............
</html>
```

I want to replace `<head>.....</head>` with ""(empty) and final string should look like this

```
<html lang="en">..............
....................
</html>
```

I tried with this but no luck nothing changed. any help is appreciated

```
 myStr= myStr.replaceAll("^<head>.*</head>$", "");

 System.out.println(myStr);
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: [don´t use regex for html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: any link for HTML parser tool @Jens

Comment: @PiyushMittal recommand libraries is of topic.

Comment: i don have much idea about parser so asked only for reference @Jens

Comment: @PiyushMittal So look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>\\s*([\\s\\S]*?)\\s*<\\/head>
```

You will have to replace by `$1` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/20

Comment: Can you give me a java sample

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String replStr  = "<head>\\s*([\\s\\S]*?)\\s*</head>";
String yourHtml = "<html> <head>   <meta http-equiv ............</head></html>";

yourHtml = yourHtml.replaceAll(replStr, "");

System.out.println("Ans :   "+yourHtml);
```