# Remove html which have class x from string in java

Tags: java, regex

Is there a good way to remove HTML from a Java string which have class "abc"? A simple regex like -

```
replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")
```

will remove all but i want to remove only those tag whose having class "abc".

```
<H1 class="abc">Hey</H1>
<H1 class="xyz">Hello</H1>
```

Remove h1 with class abc only.
Note -> have to ddo it through regex not through parser because this is the only instance where i am modifying HTML in my code. Don't want additional JAR in my code.

Comment: Don't use regex to modify a HTML file.

Comment: Just want to confirm i dont want any parser, have to do it through reg x .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You want to remove only the tags or also the text between them?

Comment: @user1803551 - tag with text as well. there should be no h1 tag and text between it which having class "abc"

Answer (score -1):

This should Work

```
replaceAll("<h1[^>]*?class=\"*\'*abc\"*\'*>.*?h1>","")
```

Comment: This would also remove `<h1>hello</h1><h2 class="abc">world</h2>`. And what should `.*?` do?

Comment: yes you are right @ctx . jst edited i think now this thing will do

Comment: .*? is "match anything infinite times till"

Comment: @XesLoohc - it's not working for me. i tried with this html and it's not removing the span tag with class "landingPage".  <h1><span class='title' id='landingPage'>Skirts Landing H1</span><span class='title' id='facetSeoPage'>Skirts Skirts SEO H1</span></h1> with regx <span[^>]*?class=\"*\'*landingPage\"*\'*>.*?span>

Comment: @Vivek It's your responsibility to provide input and expected output cases. You show a very simple case in your question and now counter an answer with complicated input that no one could have known about.

Comment: @vivek   <h1><span class='title' id='landingPage'>Skirts Landing H1</span><span class='title' id='facetSeoPage'>Skirts Skirts SEO H1</span></h1> 
here id = landingpage 
and regex is for class='landingpage'

<span[^>]*?id=\"*\'*landingPage\"*\'.*?>.*?</.*?>

I wrote it for jst a specific thing tht u mentioned

Comment: still I m considering thr is no nested html in this tag

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
replaceAll("<[Hh]1 class=['\"]landingPage['\"]>.*?</[Hh]1>", "")
```

But note that since regex is not well-suited for this task, there might be unwanted results when it comes to complex HTML input.

For the input

```
<H1 class="abc">Hey</H1>
<H1 class="xyz">Hello</H1>
```

the output is

```
<H1 class="xyz">Hello</H1>
```

Comment: Not working , returning the same string as output without removing the H1

Comment: @Vivek Works for me with the input you gave in the question. Show me how you implemented this line.

Comment: String html = "<H1 class='landingPage'>Hey</H1><H1 class='facetSeoPage'>Hello</H1>";
  System.out.println("formatted string:" 
    + html.replaceAll("<[Hh]1 class=\"landingPage\">.*</[Hh]1>","") This is removing both H1.

Comment: @Vivek What is the syntax: `class ="name"` or `class='name'`? You are using both.

Comment: It can be both..but will happy with this as well class ="name". i changed the input string to have double quotes but result is same removing both H1. String html = "<H1 class=\"landingPage\">Hey</H1><H1 class=\"facetSeoPage\">Hello</H1>";

Comment: @Vivek See my edited pattern. I made it to work with both `"` and `'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100076/discussion-between-vivek-and-user1803551).

Answer (score -2):

It's never a good idea to parse HTML using regex, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

See [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best) for alternatives.

For example, using JSoup you could write something like this (untested):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select(".abc");
elements.remove();
```

Comment: Don't add only links of other SO questions, if you think this is dupe close it as dupe.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate, so I added an example.