# JAVA How to retrieve text content from custom JLabel without the HTML taggings?

Tags: java, html, tags, label, jlabel

How do I retrieve the text from JLabel without the HTML taggings?

**E.g.**

CustomJLabel:

```
public CustomJLabel extends JLabel(){
       private String text;
    public CustomJLabel(String text) {
        super("<html><div style='text-align: center;'>"+text+"</div></html>"),
        this.text=text;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
testCustomLbl = new CustomJLabel("Testing");
System.out.println(testCustomLbl.getText());
```

Output I got:

```
<html><div style='text-align: center;'>Testing</div></html>
```

Desired output:

```
Testing
```

Comment: Please provide the code for getText() method

Comment: It's the default getText() method that returns a String.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options:

1. You pick your favorite HTML parser and parse HTML; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best) for some inspiration. This is by far the most robust and straight forward solution; but of course: costly.
2. If you are well aware of the exact HTML content that goes into your labels, then you could turn to regular expressions; or other means of string parsing. The problem is: if you don't control those strings, then coming up with your own custom "parsing" is **hard**. Because each and any change somewhere to the HTML that goes in ... might break your little parser.
3. You rework your whole design: if having HTML text is such a core thing in your application, you might consider to really "represent" that in your class. For example by creating your own versions of JLabels that take some HtmlString input ... and simply remember which parts are HTML, and which one "pure text".

And whoops; the code you are showing is already suited for option 3. So if you want that `getText()` returns that original text, you could add a simple

```
@Override
public void String getText() {
  return this.text;
}
```

to your CustomLabel class.

Edit: alternatively, you could simply add a **new** method like

```
public void String getTextWithoutHtmlTags()
```

or something alike; as *overriding* that inherited method somehow changes the "contract" of that method. Which (depending on the context) might be ok, or not so ok.

Comment: These answer does the job. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for complex code or 3rd party JARS / Libraries.
Here's a simple solution using RegEx:

```
String htmlStr = "<html><h1>Heading</h1> ...... </html>";
String noHtmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

Works great for me.
Hope this helps.