# HTML-parsing via Java

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

How do you parse html-docs in Java? I've read a lot of articles about parsing, but haven't found the best way to do it.

Comment: use jsoup. to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Jsoup https://jsoup.org/. It is one of the most widely used html parser.