# How to ignore Fatal Errors using java Sax Parer

Tags: java, saxparser

I am parsing html using java sax parser, its mostly well formatted but not all tags are terminated,
**unfortunately I cannot change the source.**
Is it possible to tell the java Sax Parser to ignore Fatal Errors ?

Errors like:

```
SAXParseException; 
The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>". 
The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
```

This is the code I am using:

```
           DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
           factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
           //factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
           // factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            Document doc = builder.parse(is);
```

Comment: no. cause it is an error and the parser does not know how to continue.

Comment: i suggest to fix these type of errors before parsing, by processing some regex replaces?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best)