# Issue with regex expression

Tags: java, android, regex

i have this tag:

```
<img data-original="http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/515.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773293_videoThumbnail.jpg" alt="I vincitori di Maria Express" class="img-responsive lazy" width="323" height="186">
```

but i need to get this: `http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/515.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_773293_videoThumbnail.jpg`

but with my regex expression `/img data-original="[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)` i am not able to get the URL...

Who can help me?

Comment: Will the text in the quotes ever _not_ be a URL? If it's always a URL, why not just match `img data-original="(.+?)"`

Comment: @Sweeper i get all tag...all attributes

Comment: @ctwheels    how i extract data-original?

Comment: @Sisso See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best) question. But basically something like [this](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) article mentions (assuming jsoup is what's being used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some contrast. This is a `"` delimited string.

Try then with:

```
img data-original="([^"]*)"
```

That way you will gather all non-`"` characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cZnv0/1).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ? This pattern allows you to get links end with .jpg

```
http(.+?)jpg
```

Or

```
http([^"]*)
```

Starts with `http` and goes until `"`

tested at [this link](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: You need only url ?

Comment: Your all links end with jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this helpful [website](https://regexr.com/) to make sure that your regex's are correct and then you should be able to copy and paste the code into Java. The website also has a nifty tool where you hightlight your regex's and it will indicate their functions. I've done this many of times to perform the regular expressions in my own code. As a final test you can copy the regular expressions into a text editor such as Notepad++ and manipulate your strings exactly as desired to guarantee they will work in Java code.