# Unable to retrieve the value of a specific text in java

Tags: java

I have a long text like below:

> name="sessionValidity" value="2018-09-13T16:28:28Z" type="hidden"
>   name="shipBeforeDate" value= "2018-09-17"  name="merchantReturnData"
>   value= "",name="shopperLocale" value="en_GB" name="skinCode"
>   value="CeprdxkMuQ" name="merchantSig"
>   value="X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4="

Now, I have to find all the data which are stored in the value string.
Please help.

Comment: Added actually it is a HTML content so it was not seen earlier. Its sorted now.

Comment: Is this value a `String`?

Comment: yep.It has multiple occurrences in the text above. I need to get some value stored in value string.

Comment: @RanjanGupta What value do you exactly want?

Comment: I need all the strings which are stored in all the value in the above text.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: It is a too long editor is not allowing me to post the full HTML.

Comment: Down voted just because *value* and *string* are frequently used words in programming. You want to parse the *value* behind *the value* and then do what with all those strings? Question stays unclear for most of the auditory...

Comment: @RanjanGupta just the part which you posted as a string with the html tags is enough. You may use a htmlparser like jsoup to get the desired values insted of string manipulation or using regex.

Comment: I can not use jsoup coz the HTML page is broken as it needs some dynamic data which are the values in the string given so thinking to replace the data under value through other solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Usually the worst thing you could do is parsing an HTML with regex. [Detailed explonation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)

**For the purpose of parsing the data and manipulate it the right way you should considering using an advanced markup parser like [jaxb](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/), [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), or [any other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best).**

*Of course it is a case specific decision and in your case maybe this one could do the work...*

```
private static List<String> extractValuesAsUselessList(String theString) {
    List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    if (theString != null && !theString.equals("")) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s([\\w+|-|:]+)=\"(.*?)\"").matcher(theString);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            if ("value".equals(matcher.group(1))) {
                attributes.add(matcher.group(2));
            }
        }
    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to modify the data through jsoup now.
I have the below html:

Comment: I think you did the right choice. Good luck with it and don't bother asking for any assistance in this direction.

Comment: I tried modifying specific value through jsoup like below:
Elements parents = doc.select("input[value]");
for (Element parent : parents)
{
System.out.println(parent.attr("value").replace("X70xAkOaaAeWGxNgWnTJolmy6/FFoFaBD47IzyBYWf4=", "Ranjan").replace("17572418", "17572418123").replace("200", "199").replace("2018-09-13T16:28:28Z", "2018-09-25T16:28:28Z").replace("2018-09-17", "2018-09-25"));
But When I print System.out.println(doc); It is printing the same old value instead I should get the modified one. How to modify the specific value which are under input tag?

Comment: please help if you have any insight to the above issue which I am facing currently.