# How to manage html code when web services response 503

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to consume web services and everything is OK but I'd like to handle html response when web service response 503 code.

This is the html response and I would like to know how to get **title** or **iframe src** value

[image: HTML response when web service response 503]

Code to call web service:

```
 ParameterCall parameterCall = new ParameterCall();
 parameterCall.setDeviceType(Constants.DEVICE_TYPE);
 Util.getRetrofit(this).parameter(parameterCall).enqueue(new Callback<ParameterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ParameterResponse> call, Response<ParameterResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus() == 1) {
                //do smt
                }else if(response.code() == 503){
                 //Here I want to show a dialog if html structure shows me the word "MANTENIMIENTO" in "body iframe"
                }
```

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

by using jsoup library you can do that, https://jsoup.org can do the job

Code Example is below

```
      String htmlString = "<html><head><title>My title</title></head>"
              + "<body>Body content</body></html>";

      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
      String title = doc.title();
```

check this link for more in detail [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best)

Comment: I want to get the title or iframe src value to do something in my app(show a dialog)

Comment: Edited the answer check.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
    if (response.code() == 200) {
       // Do your work
    }
 if (response.code() == 503) {

    }
 else {
       // Handle other condition
    }
}
```