# How can i search variable value in View page source using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here I have a scenario, where I need to check variable value from view page source code.
For ex:-  For the below URL
https://www.seniorhousingnet.com/seniorliving-detail/overture-fair-ridge-62-apartment-homes_3955-fair-ridge-drive_fairfax_va_22033-581333

Click view page source, then find an a variable "leadtype"

[image]

I know, we need to use `driver.getpagesource()` to get view page source in selenium, But I need to check `leadtype` value for a particular property, If it is `SHN-enhanced`, The logic will be different, If `leadtype` value is different then we need to apply another logic. Just please let me know how to check `leadtype` value in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to parse the HTML to get the value. That JS line is actually executed and the `adobeDTM` variable then holds the data. You can access that using `adobeDTM.leadType` but you will need to execute JavaScript in order to obtain the value.

```
String leadType = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return adobeDTM.leadType"));
```

`leadType` now contains "shn-enhanced" (according to my code execution).

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are working in java, Java provides multiple libraries for reading an html content.
once you get the page source, make an html object , parse it and reach the desired node. when you finally got the node of your choice you can get its attributes , its value and other properties as well

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
<artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
<version>1.10.2</version>
```

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
log(doc.title());
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
  log("%s\n\t%s", 
   headline.attr("title"), headline.absUrl("href"));
}
```

[JSOUP library](https://jsoup.org/)

[jsoup tutorial](https://aboullaite.me/jsoup-html-parser-tutorial-examples/)

[baeldung jsoup tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-with-jsoup)

there was also a stackoverflow question for html parser, Please do check it once [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-the-best)