# how to extract specific word from given string? I want Only MyName from the given string

Tags: java

```java
String s= "<tr><td><b>ErrorCode</b></td><td>myName</td></tr><tr><td><b>";      
String p[]= s.split(`enter code here`);
```

Comment: is the string is guaranteed to be same, After Errorcode you will get your myName?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I efficiently parse HTML with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/how-can-i-efficiently-parse-html-with-java)

Comment: [Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)  Doing so *will* break eventually.

Answer (score 1):

As per your string it looks like `HTML` and if you want to parse it, there are multiple ways to do it. As in comments one of the ways suggested is `JSOUP`.

If you are aware of the `tags` and `path` you can use `XPath` to obtain the information you need.

**For reference example as below:**

```
    String s = "<tr><td><b>ErrorCode</b></td><td>myName</td></tr>";

    InputSource inputXML = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    String xpathExpression = "/tr/td[2]"; //Xpath to evaluate and find your value as per your String.

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
    
   //It will give you List of Nodes in which you can iterate and find out your value.
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(inputXML, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getTextContent());
```

Another approach is to use Html Parsing Libraries as given in suggestions.
**JSoup**

For Jsoup (XML) below is reference code can be used.

```
    String s = "<tr><td><b>ErrorCode</b></td><td>myName</td></tr>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s,"", Parser.xmlParser());
    Elements td = doc.select("td");
    System.out.println(td.get(1).text());
```

For Jsoup(Html) your tags need to be proper.

```
    String s = "<table><tr><td><b>ErrorCode</b></td><td>myName</td></tr></table>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
    Elements td = doc.select("td");
    System.out.println(td.get(1).text());
```